# For each row in a data.table, get random index for matching rows in another data.table

Tags: r, data.table, match

I have a data.table (dt1) with several columns of factors e.g.

```
ID    Factor1    Factor2    Factor3
01          A          X          J
02          B          X          L
03          C          Y          J
```

Each row has a unique ID, but there may be multiple rows with the same combinations of Factor variables. I have another table (dt2) which has exactly the same Factor variables, but is much larger, and has no ID column. Every combination of Factors in dt1 will appear multiple times in dt2. e.g.

```
Factor1    Factor2    Factor3
      A          Z          K
      A          X          J
      A          X          J
      B          J          L
      B          X          L
      C          X          J
      C          Y          J
```

I want to return, for each row in dt1, the index of a random row in dt2 which has the same combination of Factor variables.

I figure I can use `.I[sample(.N,1)]` to return a random index, but can't figure out how to group by the relevant factors for each row. Do I need to make a function that takes each row in dt1 in turn, or is there a vectorized way to achieve this?

The desired output would either be a vector of length `nrow(dt1)`, or it could be an additional column in dt1. It would contain the row index from dt2. e.g. something like this (the Index for ID 01 could be 2 or 3):

```
ID    Factor1    Factor2    Factor3    Index
01          A          X          J        3
02          B          X          L        5
03          C          Y          J        7
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: please provide sample data of `dt2` and desired output.

Comment: @Wimpel added these

Answer (score 1):

```
# create index in dt2
dt2[, index := .I]
# set unique key dt1
setkey(dt1, ID)
# get factor columns
cols <- grep("Factor", names(dt1), value = TRUE)
#build code to eval/parse in a string
run.text <- paste0("dt1[dt1, index := sample(dt2[", 
                   paste0(cols, " == i.", cols, collapse = " & "), 
                   ", ]$index, 1), by = .EACHI]")
#eval/parse the string
eval(parse(text = run.text))
#    ID Factor1 Factor2 Factor3 index
# 1:  1       A       X       J     2
# 2:  2       B       X       L     5
# 3:  3       C       Y       J     1
# 4:  4       A       X       J     3
```

**sample data used (with duplicate in dt1)**

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- fread("ID    Factor1    Factor2    Factor3
01          A          X          J
02          B          X          L
03          C          Y          J
04          A          X          J")

dt2 <- fread("Factor1    Factor2    Factor3
      A          Z          K
      A          X          J
      A          X          J
      B          J          L
      B          X          L
      C          X          J
      C          Y          J")
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks good. In my actual use case, there are many Factor columns in dt1 and dt2 - is there a way to match them like this without having to write them all out by hand?

Comment: edited answer.. the first thing I could come up with was an eval/parse solution where you paste together the entire line before running it.. seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**
I think you want to do something like this:

```
dt2[, Index := as.character(.I)]
cols = c("Factor1", "Factor2", "Factor3")
dt = dt2[, lapply(.SD, list), keyby = cols]
dt = merge(dt1, dt, by = cols, all.x = T)
dt[, .(Index = sample(Index[[1]], 1)), keyby = c("ID", cols)]
```

Comment: Thank. As mentioned in the question, multiple rows in dt1 can have the same combination of Factor variables. With this method, they would all match to the same index - I would like the selection to be random for each row. i.e. if there are two rows in dt1 that have the same characteristics as ID 01, then I would like each to be able to match to index 2 or 3.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I update code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

1. add index
2. merge `dt1` and `dt2` then sample with `sample(.N,1)`

```
cols = names(dt2)
dt2[,index := .I]
dt2[dt1, on = (cols)][,.SD[sample(.N,1)],.(ID)]
```

or one row answer

```
dt2[,index := .I][dt1, on = (cols)][,.SD[sample(.N,1)],.(ID)]
```

### Updated

```r
library(data.table)
dt1 <- fread("ID    Factor1    Factor2    Factor3
01          A          X          J
02          B          X          L
03          C          Y          J")
dt2 <- fread("Factor1    Factor2    Factor3
      A          Z          K
      A          X          J
      A          X          J
      B          J          L
      B          X          L
      C          X          J
      C          Y          J")
cols <- names(dt2)[1:3]
dt2[,index := .I][dt1, on = (cols)][,.SD[sample(.N,1)],.(ID)]
#>       ID Factor1 Factor2 Factor3 index
#>    <int>  <char>  <char>  <char> <int>
#> 1:     1       A       X       J     3
#> 2:     2       B       X       L     5
#> 3:     3       C       Y       J     7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, I think because adding the index column also modifies the cols object.

Comment: Are you sure? I have tested it and you can see  the updated answer. Maybe you forget to initialize `dt1` and `dt2`.

Comment: Adding the index column don't modify the cols object if you check the value of `cols` after adding index column.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

# set up the data
set.seed(94)
dt1 <- setnames(as.data.table(matrix(sample(3, 9, TRUE), 3)), paste0("Factor", 1:3))
dt2 <- dt1[sample(3, 10, TRUE)]
dt1
#>    Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
#> 1:       2       1       2
#> 2:       2       3       3
#> 3:       2       3       2
dt2
#>     Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
#>  1:       2       3       2
#>  2:       2       3       3
#>  3:       2       3       2
#>  4:       2       3       2
#>  5:       2       3       2
#>  6:       2       1       2
#>  7:       2       3       2
#>  8:       2       3       2
#>  9:       2       3       2
#> 10:       2       3       3

# create helper columns and do a rolling join
dt2[, R := seq_len(.N)/.N, by = names(dt2)][, Index := .I]
print(dt2[dt1[, R := runif(.N)], on = names(dt1), roll = -Inf][, R := NULL])
#>    Factor1 Factor2 Factor3 Index
#> 1:       2       1       2     6
#> 2:       2       3       3     2
#> 3:       2       3       2     3
```